# Repeating a program using the For loop in python

Tags: python

I wrote a small program to act as a slot machine of sorts. To get full points on this assignment i need to be able to have the program run, the user gets their 3 numbers, and are told if they get any matches. I need the program to be able to run again, ideally after the user inputs the letter 'y'.

```
import random 
random_num1 = str(random.randint(0,2))
random_num2 = str(random.randint(0,2))
random_num3 = str(random.randint(0,2))
print('Python Slot Machine')

for num in random_num1:
    print(random_num1, random_num2, random_num3)
    if random_num1 == random_num2 == random_num3:
        print('You matched 3!')
    elif random_num1 == random_num2 or random_num1 == random_num3 or 
    random_num2 == random_num3:
        print('You matched 2!')
    else:
        print('You lost')
```

I had the actual program working, I just need to learn how to repeat it.

Comment: Add another for loop around what you want to repeat?

Comment: Add all the code in a function. Run it once, then create a `while True` loop. Ask for input from the user. If they input yes then run the function again else break the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is just looping over the first random number, which is definitely not what you want.  You need a "forever" loop, which exits when the user wants to stop.  Note that you need to allocate the numbers INSIDE that loop.  Also note that you don't need to convert to strings.

```
import random 
print('Python Slot Machine')

while True:
    random_num1 = random.randint(0,2)
    random_num2 = random.randint(0,2)
    random_num3 = random.randint(0,2)

    print(random_num1, random_num2, random_num3)
    if random_num1 == random_num2 == random_num3:
        print('You matched 3!')
    elif random_num1 == random_num2 or random_num1 == random_num3 or random_num2 == random_num3:
        print('You matched 2!')
    else:
        print('You lost')

    if input("Go again?  y/n: ") == "n":
        break
```